# tags are not being created for api gateway

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

```
  Api:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
Properties:
  Name: test
  Tags:
    - Key: test
      Value: "true"
```

I have the above CloudFormation definition as part of the stack. After deployment, all the resources are created successfully except the Tags off the Api Gateway.

There is no error in Events tab and I tried to delete and redeploy the stack but it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to **replicate**, but I haven't experienced any issues. Your tags are correct and they are **created as expected**:

[image]

Comment: maybe delete the stack and redeploy?

Comment: @Lys If you can it's worth trying.